# My jQuery click event is looping and outputting wierd results

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, events

When you press the submit button this happens:
- Check if all inputs are filled
- if so, check inputs that only accept numbers (it fails if this input has a letter)
- post products into back-end

If I don't fill all inputs it will display I output a message saying "please fill all inputs". Great it's working

But if I put letters in the numbers fields the message will change from "please fill all inputs" and "please only enter numbers" really quickly, looping between them.

I've tried returning the event null if the validation is failed, and doing event.stopImmediatePropagation() if the validation fails.

//submit button

```
$('#submitNewProduct').click((e)=>{

        e.preventDefault();

        productName     =   $('#product_name').val();
        pricePerUnit    =   $('#price_PerUnit').val();
        productDescp    =   $('#product_Description').val();
        productAmmount  =   $('#product_Ammount').val();

        if(!productName || !pricePerUnit || !productDescp || !productAmmount){

            ajaxMessaging('red','Fill inputs');


        }else if(isNaN(pricePerUnit) || isNaN(productAmmount)){

            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            ajaxMessaging('red','Ints');
        }else{
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:5000/dashboard',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    product_name : $('#product_name').val(),
                    price_PerUnit : $('#price_PerUnit').val(),
                    product_Description : $('#product_Description').val(),
                    product_Ammount: $('#product_Ammount').val(),
                }),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: ajaxMessaging('green', 'Submited')
            });
        }
    });


//messaging function
function ajaxMessaging(color, text){

        setInterval(()=>{
            $('#ajaxMessage').css('background-color' , color);
            $('#ajaxMessage').slideDown(500);
            $('#ajaxMessage').text(text);
            $('#ajaxCloseMSG').delay(500).fadeIn(500);
        },500);
    }
```

Comment: Is the `submitNewProduct` button in a form?  Is it's type="submit" or no type at all?   If so your button is trying to submit your form cause validation and it's trying to run your click event.

Comment: I have a setInterval method where I should call a setTimeout, im so dumb lol. Do you know how to delete a post?

Comment: Right under the list of tags for the post should be some commands.  Including delete.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use a **setInterval**?

This triggers first the empty message (first click and one or several fields are empty) and then when data is wrong (at the second click on the button) the second error message is displayed. Both are running in a infinite loop every 500ms because of this **setInterval** (have a look here: [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)).

Just remove the **setInterval** or if you want to have control over the time **before** it is displayed just use a **setTimeout** instead.

Hope it helps